# Converting coordinates supplied by DDMS into location

Tags: android, eclipse, location, ddms

I am creating a service that will give updates on the users location every 5 minutes. I am using the DDMS to send the coordinates to the emulator. I want to convert the coordinates and find the location. How can i do this? I am new to android Please help. This is my code so far

```
 public class GetLocationService extends Service {
protected LocationManager locationManager;
Button start;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new MyLocListener();
    Location location = new Location("abc");
    ll.onLocationChanged(location ); 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);
    return START_STICKY;
}

 private class MyLocListener implements LocationListener {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
    Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
    Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
    }
    Toast.makeText(GetLocationService.this,
    location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean get location (address in a map like Google map) from latitude and longitude?

Comment: No i am not using any maps. I meant something like using geocoder class to convert the coordinates into location

Comment: Could you explain the location you want? Is it an position that user can understand such as '620 Eighth Avenue New York, USA'?

Comment: Yes it is.Just getting it as New York is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
try{
 Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(youractivityclassname.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
  if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
        yourtextfieldname.setText("Waiting for Location");
  }
  else {
     if (addresses.size() > 0) {       
        Log.d(TAG,addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", 
         " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", 
         " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ",
         " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());

     }
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There is a syntax mistake near .getFeatureName()

Comment: I have checked, this mistake occur when I break line when post in this page. You should remove break line when copy and paste.